# При sql запросе (SELECT * FROM `goods` WHERE 'id'='$good_id') выдает объект, а не массив!

Tags: php, sql

Проблема в том, что при sql запросе не выводится строка таблицы по id, а выводится объект с параметрами строки - [image: mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 4 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 ).]

В ($_GET['id']) значение с другого файла передается правильно (цифрами).

Так же mysqli_fetch_assoc не выводит значения переменной $good2 (Потому что в переменной $good объект, с этим и проблема).

```
<?php
$good_id = $_GET['id'];
require_once 'config/connect.php';
$request = "SELECT * FROM `goods` WHERE 'id'='$good_id'";
$good = mysqli_query($connect, $request);
$good2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($good);

print_r($good);
print_r($good2);
?>
```

Буду благодарен, если поможете решить данную проблему, которую я без понятия, как решить.

Comment: проблема в том, что в $good num_rows = 0, так что непонятно какой массив вы хотите получить из результата в 0 строк

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ожидаемое поведение. `mysqli_query` возвращает объект типа `mysqli_result`, с помощью которого можно достать значения из БД используя функции типа `mysqli_fetch_row`, `mysqli_fetch_object` и т.п. (смотрите полный список в [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)):

```
   $res = mysqli_query($connect, $request, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
   if ($res) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) {
         print("col1: ".$row[0]."\n");
         print("col2: ".$row[1]."\n");
      }
   }
```

И как в комментариях вам написал `ArchDemon` тут у вас проблема, что запрос вернул пустой список. И как правильно отметил u_mulder у вас  проблема в запросе, он делает не то, что вы ожидаете. Запись `'id'`, т.е. в кавычках, сравнивает строку `id` со значением параметра, и ясно что ничего не находит.

Вообще, очень плохая идея строить запрос путем манипуляции со строками. Это очень [небезопасно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Правильно использовать связываемые переменные:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM goods WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    print("col1: ".$row['col1']);
    print("col2: ".$row['col2']);
  }
}

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Запись-то наверняка есть, а вот зачем оборачивать в кавычки название поля - это вопрос.

Comment: Это, кстати, тоже.